# Cut the row that has a green cells and past it under the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of A5:E40. the row is dynamic and could become longer than 40. 
When I add a date in the range (B5:Lastrow), the range A:E where the date has been added becomes green.

I want to cut the row that is green, past it below the last row in the table and without leaving the empty spaces by cutting the row.

I have the following code but it does not work correctly. it past the row but nut in the last row

```
Dim b As Integer

For b = 5 To LastRow
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & b).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").rows(b).Cut _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & LastRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    End If
Next b
```

Comment: You'll have to calculate that `LastRow` variable inside your `If` block before you do the `.Cut`. Something like `LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @JNevill I'd be careful with that, as `LastRow` is the bounds of the `For` iterator, there's usually problems when modifying an iterator within the loop!

Comment: Note that all row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle!